# Embedded IF AND Statements in Excel

Tags: excel

I searched around on this site and found something similar to what I need, but I haven't been able to get it to work for me yet.  I was able to get it to work when I do only half of it, but when I try to work in the other 2 conditions with AND statements, it gets messed up and I can't figure out what's going wrong.

The partial string of code that worked for me is this
    =IF(M7>O7, IF(P7="R", 3, IF(P7="O", 2, IF)))

I have statements that would give different output...

```
If m7>o7 and p7="R" output a value of 3
If m7>o7 and p7="O" output a value of 2
If o7>m7 and p7="O" output a value of 1
If o7>m7 and p7="R" output a value of 0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could do this without an `IF` relatively easily: `=AND(M7>O7,P7="R")*3 + AND(M7>O7,P7="O")*2 + AND(M7<O7,P7="O")*1`  Or without `AND` even: `=(M7>O7)*(P7="R")*3 + (M7>O7)*(P7="O")*2 + (M7<O7)*(P7="O")*1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(M7>O7,IF(P7="R",3,2),IF(P7="R",0,1))
```

---

Per the comment:

```
=IF(AND(M7<>"",O7<>"",P7<>""),IF(M7>O7,IF(P7="R",3,2),IF(P7="R",0,1)),"")
```

Comment: One more question...  Is there a way to have it display nothing if none of those are true (like before m7, o7 and p7 are populated)?

Comment: @TraciL see edit, remember to mark as correct if it is the formula you use, by clicking the check mark by the answer.